# Turtle subclass doesn't draw a straight line

Tags: python, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

I am trying to build a subclass that inherited from `turtle.Turtle` class and want to create a function to automatically draw the polygon. But I find the initial line always tilts a bit.
I don't know where's the problem.

Here's the code:

```
import turtle

class Polygon(turtle.Turtle):
    def __init__(self, point_list):
        self.point_list = point_list

    def add_point(self, point):
        self.point_list.append(point)
        return self.point_list

    def over_write_points(self, new_points):
        self.point_list = new_points
        return self.point_list

    def perimeter(self):
        length_peri = 0
        for i in range(len(self.point_list)):
            point1 = self.point_list[i-1]
            point2 = self.point_list[i]
            x1, y1 = point1
            x2, y2 = point2
            length = ((x1 - x2)**2 + (y1 - y2)**2)*0.5
            length_peri += length
        return length_peri

    def area(self):
        area = 0
        for i in range(len(self.point_list)):
            point1 = self.point_list[i-1]
            point2 = self.point_list[i]
            x1, y1 = point1
            x2, y2 = point2
            trapezoid = ((x2 - x1) * (y1 + y2)) / 2
            area = area + trapezoid
        area = abs(area)
        return area

    def bound_points(self):
        unzip_list = list(zip(*self.point_list))
        x_list = unzip_list[0]
        y_list = unzip_list[1]
        bound1 = max(x_list), min(y_list)
        bound2 = max(x_list), max(y_list)
        bound3 = min(x_list), max(y_list)
        bound4 = min(x_list), min(y_list)
        bound_points = [bound1, bound2, bound3, bound4]
        return bound_points

    def move_poly(self, dx, dy):
        new_point_list = []
        for i in self.point_list:
            x = i[0] + dx
            y = i[1] + dy
            new_point = (x, y)
            new_point_list.append(new_point)
        self.point_list = new_point_list
        return self.point_list

    def draw_poly(self, lineColour="green", fillColour="yellow"):
        start = self.point_list[-1]
        turtle.pencolor(lineColour)
        turtle.fillcolor(fillColour)

        turtle.penup()
        turtle.pendown()
        turtle.begin_fill()

        x, y = start
        for point in self.point_list:  # go through a list of points
            dx, dy = point
            turtle.goto(x + dx, y + dy)

        turtle.end_fill()
        turtle.penup()
        turtle.mainloop()
        return f'The polygon is finished'


    test_polygon = Polygon([(50,0), (50,50), (0,50)])
    print(test_polygon.add_point((0, 0)))
    print(test_polygon.over_write_points([(100,0), (100,100), (0,100), (0,0)]))
    print(test_polygon.perimeter())
    print(test_polygon.area())
    print(test_polygon.bound_points())
    print(test_polygon.move_poly(-10,-10))
    print(test_polygon.draw_poly())
```

Comment: See how to create a [mcve]. Delete as much code as you can and still have it fail your expectations.

Comment: You never move the `turtle` to the initial `start` position in your `draw_poly()` method (with the pen up),

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've several problems in your code.  First, as @martineau notes (+1), you start drawing from the turtle's home position rather than the first position in your list.  (And you need to close the polygon by returning back to that first position.)

The math in your `perimeter()` function seems wrong:

```
length = ((x1 - x2)**2 + (y1 - y2)**2)*0.5
```

That should probably be `**0.5` to calculate the square root, not half.  You forgot to call `super()` in your `__init__` function.

Also, your `draw_poly()` is *calling functions* in module `turtle` instead of *invoking methods* on `self`.  This is why I do `import Screen, Turtle`  instead of `import turtle`, just to avoid this error.

Below is a rework of your code with the above and other fixes:

```
from turtle import Turtle

class Polygon(Turtle):
    def __init__(self, point_list):
        super().__init__()

        self.point_list = point_list

    def add_point(self, point):
        self.point_list.append(point)

        return self.point_list

    def over_write_points(self, new_points):
        self.point_list[:] = new_points  # reload existing list

        return self.point_list

    def perimeter(self):
        length_peri = 0

        for i in range(len(self.point_list)):
            point1 = self.point_list[i - 1]
            point2 = self.point_list[i]
            x1, y1 = point1
            x2, y2 = point2
            length = ((x1 - x2)**2 + (y1 - y2)**2)**0.5
            length_peri += length

        return length_peri

    def area(self):
        area = 0

        for i in range(len(self.point_list)):
            point1 = self.point_list[i - 1]
            point2 = self.point_list[i]
            x1, y1 = point1
            x2, y2 = point2
            trapezoid = ((x2 - x1) * (y1 + y2)) / 2
            area += trapezoid

        return abs(area)

    def bound_points(self):
        unzip_list = list(zip(*self.point_list))

        x_list = unzip_list[0]
        y_list = unzip_list[1]

        bound1 = max(x_list), min(y_list)
        bound2 = max(x_list), max(y_list)
        bound3 = min(x_list), max(y_list)
        bound4 = min(x_list), min(y_list)

        return [bound1, bound2, bound3, bound4]

    def move_poly(self, dx, dy):
        new_point_list = []

        for x, y in self.point_list:
            new_point = (x + dx, y + dy)
            new_point_list.append(new_point)

        return self.over_write_points(new_point_list)

    def draw_poly(self, lineColour='green', fillColour='yellow'):
        self.pencolor(lineColour)
        self.fillcolor(fillColour)

        start, *remaining_points = self.point_list

        self.penup()
        self.goto(start)
        self.pendown()

        self.begin_fill()

        for point in remaining_points:  # go through a list of points
            self.goto(point)

        self.goto(start)
        self.end_fill()
        self.penup()

        return 'The polygon is finished'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    from turtle import Screen

    screen = Screen()

    test_polygon = Polygon([(50, 0), (50, 50), (0, 50)])
    print(test_polygon.add_point((0, 0)))
    print(test_polygon.over_write_points([(100, 0), (100, 100), (0, 100), (0, 0)]))
    print(test_polygon.perimeter(), "pixels")
    print(test_polygon.area(), "pixels squared")
    print(test_polygon.bound_points())
    print(test_polygon.move_poly(-10, -10))
    print(test_polygon.draw_poly())

    screen.exitonclick()
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It's very clear and helpful. Indeed, I still have a lot to learn. I will keep practicing!

Comment: I suggest using [`math,hypot()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html#math.hypot) to compute the lenght. It's faster and less prone to error.